# TypeError: MyUserManager.create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to create a super-user using this command: "python manage.py createsuperuser", but I can't. Here's the error: "TypeError: MyUserManager.create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'".

Here's my code:
'''

class MyUserManager(UserManager):

```
def create_superuser(self, username: str, email: str | None, password: str | None, **extra_fields: Any) -> Any:
    self.username = extra_fields['phone']
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
    return super().create_superuser(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

def create_user(self, username: str, email: str | None = ..., password: str | None = ..., **extra_fields: Any) -> Any:
    username = extra_fields['phone']
    return super().create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
```

'''

Comment: You've told it username is a required positional argument, then you haven't given it when you've run the command!

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you, that the function requires a keyword argument named `username`.
So you most likely need to call the function like this

```py
return super().create_superuser(username=username, email=email, password=password, **extra_fields)
```

Quick side note: One could be tempted to just do this

```py
return super().create_superuser(username=username, email, password, **extra_fields)
```

which won't work as keyword arguments can't be followed by normal arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove it `REQUIRED_FIELDS=['username']` because by default in django it is username